# Inserir Planilha do Google Drive em Website

Tags: html, iframe, google

Estou programando um site HTML/CSS, mas o cliente precisa atualizar uma planilha que fica na capa do site.

Eu consegui inserir uma planilha criada no Google Drive, através de um iFrame, mas ela fica com barras brancas na lateral e também com o título, gostaria que aparecesse somente o conteúdo.

Tem algum outro modo de fazer isso sem utilizar CMS?

Comment: Você usou a funcionalidade de publicação da planilha no Google Drive? Essas barras brancas são o que exatamente? Para mim aparecem umas barras brancas, mas são apenas as barras de rolagem.

Comment: Sim, utilizei essa funcionalidade, e no iFrame desabilitei as barras de rolagem, ai ficam essas barras brancas que não consigo retirar, assim como o título da planilha.

Comment: Nesse caso uma opção pode ser na hora da publicação você escolher um range de células para mostrar. Fica lá na tela da publicação mesmo. Dessa forma, em vez de mostrar o título, só vai mostrar as células selecionadas.

Comment: Eu defini um range no próprio iFrame, mas mesmo assim aparecem as bordas. E procurei na publicação e não tem escolha de células.

Comment: Pra remover a barra tenta colocar no css overflow: hidden; e na tag <iframe scrolling="no" seamless="seamless">

Comment: Vejam a imagem, ainda não fiz a modificação que o @Kallef fez. Vou fazer hoje a noite... http://s29.postimg.org/w8ugb80s7/10540371_10204297564578426_484421771_n.jpg

Comment: @Kallef, não funcionou colocar o seamless, e nem o overflow.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode forçar um elemento ao redor do `IFRAME` de maneira a deslocar o conteúdo que você não quer ver para fora do *viewport*. Exemplo:

```
<style type="text/css">
#iframe-holder {
    overflow:hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top:-430px;
    bottom:0px;
    left:0;
    right:0;
 }
#iframe-holder iframe {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
 }
</style>

<div id="iframe-holder">
<iframe src="http://www.wired.com/" frameborder="0"  name="main" scrolling="no"></iframe>
</div>
```

Conteúdo original:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

`IFRAME` dentro de um *wrapper* com posicionamento explícito, deslocando 430 pixels para cima. Note que o bloco inicial excluído:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Muito obrigado! Quase funcionou, consegui cortar as bordas, mas a tabela apareceu lá em cima do cabeçalho, longe do box que ela deveria estar... e parece que tem uma máscara na frente do cabeçalho que faz com que ele não funcione.

Comment: @JefSilva Imagino que seja apenas uma questão de posicionamento. Não desista! =)

Comment: sim é uma questão de posicionamento, mas como colocar a planilha dentro do box que estava antes? Se apenas tinha colocado o iFrame dentro da div no html?

Comment: Já tentei mover o iFrame pra todos os lados e ele continua "trancando" o que está por baixo. Ele não obedece a div superior...